# Hazelcast discovery in Openshift: Connection reset warnings to routers IPs

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, hazelcast

Openshift routers update from version 3.7 to version 3.9 caused hundreds of warnings in Openshift logs:

```
[timestamp] [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-2] WARN com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection - [x.x.19.150]:5701 [dev] [3.11.4] Connection[id=157132, /x.x.19.150:5701->/x.x.25.1:50370, endpoint=null, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=157132, /x.x.19.150:5701->/x.x.25.1:50370, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=NONE], thread=hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-2 java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
[timestamp] [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-0] WARN  com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection - [x.x.31.153]:5701 [dev] [3.11.4] Connection[id=156553, /x.x.31.153:5701->/x.x.9.1:48700, endpoint=null, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=156553, /x.x.31.153:5701->/x.x.9.1:48700, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=NONE], thread=hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-0\njava.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer\n at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
[timestamp] [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-2] WARN  com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection - [x.x.3.34]:5701 [dev] [3.11.4] Connection[id=157179, /x.x.3.34:5701->/x.x.25.1:60596, endpoint=null, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=157179, /x.x.3.34:5701->/x.x.25.1:60596, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=NONE]
[timestamp] [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-1] WARN  com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection - [x.x.10.75]:5701 [dev] [3.11.4] Connection[id=157171, /x.x.10.75:5701->/x.x.25.1:33826, endpoint=null, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=157171, /x.x.10.75:5701->/x.x.25.1:33826, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=NONE]
[timestamp] [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-1] WARN  com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection - [x.x.27.206]:5701 [dev] [3.11.4] Connection[id=157157, /x.x.27.206:5701->/x.x.25.1:49578, endpoint=null, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=157157, /x.x.27.206:5701->/x.x.25.1:49578, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=NONE]
[timestamp] [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-1] WARN  com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection - [x.x.31.153]:5701 [dev] [3.11.4] Connection[id=157127, /x.x.31.153:5701->/x.x.25.1:42506, endpoint=null, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=157127, /x.x.31.153:5701->/x.x.25.1:42506, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=NONE]
```

Issue was temporary "solved" by roll back to version 3.7: no warnings in Hazelcast logs anymore.

**Current findings:**

- All exceptions contain IPs that end to x.x.x.1. That are Openshift routers IPs.
- Target ports are 50370, 48700, 60596, 39840, 35046, 59900, etc.

**hazelcast.xml:**

```
...
<properties>
    <property name="hazelcast.discovery.enabled">true</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">slf4j</property>
</properties>
<network>
    <port port-count="1" auto-increment="false">5701</port>
    <reuse-address>true</reuse-address>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false"/>
        <kubernetes enabled="true">
            <namespace>project-name</namespace>
            <service-name>hazelcast-discovery</service-name>
        </kubernetes>
    </join>
</network>
```

**Versions details:**

- Hazelcast version: 3.11.4
- OpenShift Master: v3.9.68 (Kubernetes Master: v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657), routers version 3.9

**Misc:**

- The issue is not reproduced with another cluster (Openshift 3.11, router 3.9, Hazelcast 3.11.4)
- The issue was reproduced in the same cluster with Hazelcast version 3.10.

**Questions:**

- What is the root cause of these warnings?
- Can we tune our configuration to avoid such connections?

Would it help?

- remove `<property name="hazelcast.discovery.enabled">true</property>`
- add `<tcp-ip enabled="false"></tcp-ip>`
  (I didn’t find in hazelcast documentation what is default value for tcp-ip. Official [example](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/3.11.5/hazelcast-integration/kubernetes/config.yaml) of hazelcast.xml explicitly set tcp-ip to false.)

**Edit 24.10.2019**. Deployment details:

- Application and Hazelcast are in the same project. Application
  connects to hazelcast by service name: hazelcast:5701
- We use custom
  livenessProbe/readinessProbe that start bash script every 10s. See below.
- We have also have a route for Hazelcast. Endpoint /hazelcast/rest/cluster showed correct number of members.
- Here is full hazelcast config: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1907166
  Are our service settings correct?

bash script for probes:

```
#!/bin/bash
URL="http://127.0.0.1:5701/hazelcast/health/node-state"
HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl -m 5 -sS $URL | head -1)
if [ "_${HTTP_RESPONSE}" != "_ACTIVE" ]; then
  echo "failure on ${URL}, response: ${HTTP_RESPONSE}"
  exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

**Edit 25.10.2019**:

```
$ oc describe svc hazelcast-discovery
Name:              hazelcast-discovery
Namespace:         [project-name]
Labels:            app=hazelcast
                   template=hazelcast-statefulset-template
Annotations:       service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints=true

Selector:          name=hazelcast-node-cluster
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                None
Port:              5701-tcp  5701/TCP
TargetPort:        5701/TCP
Endpoints:         x.x.1.45:5701,x.x.12.144:5701,x.x.13.251:5701 and more...
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Pods were restarted after the issue, so IPs might differ from the logs.
Could it be connected to `tolerate-unready-endpoints=true`?

Comment: I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516419/does-istio-support-hazelcast-kubernetes. We are not using istio.

Comment: I am unfortunately unfamiliar with Openshift Routers. hazelcast.discovery.enabled is not needed in k8s environment so you can remove. tcp-ip is by default disabled so you do not need to configure it. This warning happens when a member loses the connection to the other member.

Comment: Can you share your openshift deployment configs too? Are those 5 members your all members of the hazelcast cluster or part of it?

Comment: As mentioned by @Mesut, changing `tcp-ip` or removing `hazelcast.discovery.enabled` won't solve the issue. It looks like OpenShift routers connect to Hazelcast cluster and then drop the connections. So the possible causes for that can be: 1) OpenShift routers do the health check calls (not critical) 2) OpenShift routers connection fails for some reason (critical). The first thing you should check is if everything works correctly from OpenShift routers perspective.

Comment: @Mesut "This warning happens when a member loses the connection to the other member". Are there any other cases? We checked  /hazelcast/rest/cluster endpoint periodically. AFAIK number of cluster members was not changed. I will add details about deployment.

Comment: I've added a link to our hazelcast configuration.

Comment: What do you see as endpoint list when you describe hazelcast-discovery ? oc describe svc hazelcast-discovery. normally those are the endpoints each member is trying to form a cluster. The other possibility as outgoing connection is to connect to Management Center or WAN replication.

Comment: @Mesut endpoint list contains IPs of hazelcast pods. Number of IPs is the same is hazelcast pods number. Note: I don't have output of this command during the issue as we rolled back routers.

Comment: Ok I see. One last question. Do you really need a route between hazelcast members? Maybe try to remove it in the deployment and see what happens. Discovery is done through Kubernetes API so dns is needed. All communication is done through IPs. Other than that I suggest to open a ticket here referencing this SO question so someone can have a look Hazelcast Deployment Openshift Routes. https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes/issues/new

Comment: @Mesut: thanks for the questions. I've also thought if route is a must for us. Currently route is used for external monitoring only.